# Simplest recursive SNARK working example

Tags: zksnark, recursive

I have been doing some research into [recursive SNARKs](https://cs251.stanford.edu/lectures/lecture18.pdf). But I haven't found a working code example such as [this one](https://zokrates.github.io/gettingstarted.html#hello-zokrates) using Zokrates or this one using [snarkjs](https://blog.iden3.io/first-zk-proof.html). Anyone knows one such example, say, for proving a [hash chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_chain)?

Recursive STARK example is also fine.